# Fade Radial js ou canvas

Tags: jquery, animação, canvas

Olá, gostaria de saber se há alguma transição que eu possa fazer em radial ou estilo de tinta dissolvendo (como se fosse tinta escorrendo)? Para esse efeito ficar mais legal para abrir o site.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xos841uf/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('.fase_1').fadeIn(200);
        $('.fase_2').delay(300).fadeIn(200);
        $('.fase_3').delay(800).fadeIn(200);
    
})
```

```css
#preload{position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:50;overflow:hidden;}
#preload div{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;display:none;}
#preload div img{height:100%;width:100%;}
#preload{background-color: #2F2727;background-image: url(../images/bg_verde.jpg);background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:cover;background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(#236a0f), to(#133e08));background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #236a0f, #133e08);background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #236a0f, #133e08);background: -ms-radial-gradient(circle, #236a0f, #133e08);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preload">
        <div class="fase_1">
            <img src="http://www.matcha.provisorio.ws/images/fase_1.png" alt="Fase1" />
        </div>
        <div class="fase_2">
            <img src="http://www.matcha.provisorio.ws/images/fase_2.png" alt="Fase1" />
        </div>
        <div class="fase_3">
            <img src="http://www.matcha.provisorio.ws/images/fase_3.png" alt="Fase1" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

fiz um exemplo (na verdade atualizei o seu exemplo)

[Código com exemplo de animação](http://jsfiddle.net/xos841uf/6/)

... onde usei a animação pura de CSS.

É necessário setar as posições e delays para conseguir um efeito melhor. Ainda é possível inverter a direção da animação, mudando este trecho de CSS.

```css
@keyframes tinta {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    , to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
        display:block
    }
}
```

Invertendo os valores da propriedade transform : scale(x);

Espero que tenha ajudado.